# Limit Neo4j apoc.path.expand by relationship property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Is it possible in a weighted Neo4j graph to find all paths within n hops of a given node with the constraints that only the top m relationships (by weight) from each node are returned/further expanded?

For example, given the following graph:

[image]

This query...

```
MATCH (n0:Foo {n: "a"})
CALL apoc.path.expand(n0, "TO>", "", 1, 3)
YIELD path as p
WHERE ALL (x in relationships(p) where x.score > 0.02)  // Additional constraint not directly related to the question
RETURN p, length(p) AS hops
ORDER BY hops
```

... returns:

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════╕
│"p"                                                                    │"hops"│
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════╡
│[{"n":"a"},{"score":0.03},{"n":"d"}]                                   │1     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────┤
│[{"n":"a"},{"score":0.03},{"n":"d"},{"n":"d"},{"score":0.11},{"n":"k"}]│2     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────┤
│[{"n":"a"},{"score":0.03},{"n":"d"},{"n":"d"},{"score":0.1},{"n":"j"}] │2     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────┤
│[{"n":"a"},{"score":0.03},{"n":"d"},{"n":"d"},{"score":0.12},{"n":"l"}]│2     │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────┘
```

Is it possible to also **limit the outgoing relationships from each node to e.g. the top 2 by score**.

The expected output would be:

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════╕
│"p"                                                                    │"hops"│
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════╡
│[{"n":"a"},{"score":0.03},{"n":"d"}]                                   │1     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────┤
│[{"n":"a"},{"score":0.03},{"n":"d"},{"n":"d"},{"score":0.11},{"n":"k"}]│2     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────┤
│[{"n":"a"},{"score":0.03},{"n":"d"},{"n":"d"},{"score":0.12},{"n":"l"}]│2     │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in one go, because you you have to compare for each step in each path.

Also you have to think of the case where you have scores like 0.09,0.11,0.11,0,12
in which taking the top 2 could return arbitrary results.

```
MATCH p=(n0)-[:TO*1..3]->()
// From starting node
WHERE n0.n='a'
// get for each node the scores of the outgoing reps, sort them and get the second one
// and put them in an array
WITH p,
     REDUCE (array=[], n IN [x in nodes(p) WHERE (x)-[:TO]->()] |
             (array
             + apoc.coll.sort([(n)-[r:TO]->() | r.score])[1])
            ) AS cutOffScoresByStep
WITH p,cutOffScoresByStep

// only get the paths where the score on each rel is higher than the corresponding cutOffScore
WHERE ALL (rel IN relationships(p) 
           WHERE rel.score >= cutOffScoresByStep[apoc.coll.indexOf(relationships(p),rel)]
          )
             
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. There was one issue I ran into with this solution on leaf nodes (i.e. nodes without a `:TO` relationship) in the reduction step where it would return null for `r.score` and reducing that would result in `array` being null. I edited your original answer to include a `WHERE` clause in the `REDUCE` functions list expression. I also added a start node and reversed the comparison in the final `WHERE ALL` clause to match my original question. Thanks again!